# php 5.3.2 version

Tags: php

I have downloaded a php 5.3.2. (.zip) from offical website.
In  directory  'php/ext' ,there are no files  php_mssql.dll,php_pgsql.dll,php_curl.dll lybaries.

where can i find it? 
Is it supported  Php 5.3.2 ?
other libary are ok.(mysql)

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/webserver/php/ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/webserver/php/ext\\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/webserver/php/ext\\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Thu May 13 16:17:57 2010] [notice] Child 2212: Child process is runningified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Which file did you download? Also, did you download from the PHP Windows site (http://windows.php.net/download/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want PHP with batteries then you can always download a WAMP software bundle. For example xampp from http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: Are there "Linux Apache MySQL PHP" bundles for Windows? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the extensions are not bundled by default, this link explains it in details "Some of these DLLs are not bundled with the PHP distribution. See each extensions documentation page for details."

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Answer (score 0):

Most extensions are on [Pierre's page](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, I downloaded version 5.3.2 of PHP and it does not come with the library php_mssql.dll. From what I've read, there is more support for it in this version of PHP. Should be used to php_sqlsrv.dll and their functions.
Should be used to php_sqlsrv.dll and their functions
Someone confirm this my last statement?